# How can I change the sites url depending on the anchor tags?

Tags: django, django-templates, anchor, django-urls

`urls.py`:

```
app_name='listing'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^listing/select/$',views.platformselect,name='listingselect'),
    url(r'^listing/',views.listingpage,name='listingpage'),

]
```

`views.py`:

```
def platformselect(request):
    
    return render(request,'listing/platform_select.html')
```

`platform_selection.html`:

```
<a href="{% url 'listing:listingpage' %}">amazon</a>
<a href="{% url 'listing:listingpage' %}">ebay</a>
<a href="{% url 'listing:listingpage' %}">google</a>
```

Greetings. How can I change the urls according to the `<a>` options. For example when I click the '`amazon`' anchor tag I want it go to "`mysite.com/listing/amazon`". Same for the other options. How can I change the sites `url` depending on the anchor tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to make slight changes according to your project:

In your `urlpatterns`:

```
path("listing/<int:id>/", views.listing_detail, name="listing-detail"),
```

In your template:

```
<a href="{% url 'listing:listing-detail' listing.id %}">{{ listing.name }}</a>
```

In your view function:

```
def listing_detail(request, id):
    listing = Listings.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, "listing/listing_detail.html", {
        "listing": listing
    })
```